# Acquiring WifiLock: is really necessary?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-location, android-wireless

I'm developing an app which uses wifi-direct to create a group and join it in order to share friends locations. My question is: given the fact that wifi-direct is "disabled" after some time to save energy, is keeping a WifiLock the only solution i have to be permanently visible to other people searching for my group?

Thanks

Comment: Does it get disable even after the connection has established or during discovery phase only...?

Comment: Yes, also after a connect() phase.

Comment: Have you tested this on multiple devices and are you sure it is not something happening due to deep sleep?

Comment: I'm testing on a cell phone and on a tablet with wifi-only, and happens also when my screen is on.

Comment: Although android's wifi-direct framework is pretty unstable and I have personally stopped using it for connecting two (or more) devices, but I still feel it shouldn't disconnect on its own after establishing connection.